# Actualización Manual en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo desarrollada una app en android, como es para una empresa no puede estar en la Play Store, actualmente cuando hago una modificiación tengo que enviar la apk al administrador de dicha empresa y el la reparte por correo, lo que quiero hacer es que la aplicación al iniciarse consuma mi Web Service (esto ya lo hice) y al ver que cambió la versión, descargue la nueva versión y la instale automáticamente desinstalando la versión vieja

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres complicarte? En Play Store puedes [publicar aplicaciones privadas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992#admin-console) o puedes publicarla en modo Alfa o Beta testing y distribuirla desde Play Console a los usuarios autorizados a usarla. Incluso Play Console tiene una opción tipo Lista de distribución para este propósito.

Comment: Osea en realidad no depende de mí XD, yo sugerí también la play store pero fue rechazado así que no se en realidad como hacer para descargar la nueva actualización e instalarla automáticamente

Comment: Entiendo, pero es una pena renunciar a esas ventajas por algo que implica solamente complicarse la vida. En fin... La lógica es clara, en el Main de la app pones un número de versión que estaría también en el WS, comparas si son iguales y cuando no lo sean tendrás que lanzar código para que desinstale esa App, descargue la APK nueva y la instale. Tendrás que ver si Android tiene código para poder hacer esta última parte que será la más trabajosa.